# Class Component throwing erros ' TypeError: Cannot destructure property 'timerTime' of 'this.State' as it is undefined'

Tags: javascript, reactjs, components, state

I'm throwing an error here that I think has to do with scope.  It doesn't like the way state (defined at the top) and the destructured state (in the render) are communicating.  What can you see? The error reads: TypeError: Cannot destructure property 'timerTime' of 'this.State' as it is undefined.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'

// this was sources from: https://medium.com/@peterjd42/building-timers-in-react-stopwatch-and-countdown-bc06486560a2

export default class Countdown extends Component {
  state = {
    timerOn: false,
    timerStart: 0,
    timerTime: 0
  }

  startTimer = () => {
    this.state({
      timerOn: true,
      timerStart: this.state.timerTime,
      timerTime: this.state.timerTime
    })
    this.timer = setInterval(() => {
      const newTime = this.state.timerTime - 10
      if (newTime >= 0) {
        this.setState({
          timerTime: newTime
        })
      } else {
        clearInterval(this.timer)
        this.setState({ timerOn: false })
        alert("Countdown ended")
      }
    }, 10)
  }

  stopTimer = () => {
    clearInterval(this.timer)
    this.setState({timerOn: false})
  }

  resetTimer = () => {
    if (this.state.timerOn === false) {
      this.setState({
        timerTime: this.state.timerStart
      })
    }
  }

  adjustTimer = input => {
    const { timerTime, timerOn } = this.state
    const max = 216000000
    if (!timerOn) {
      if (input === 'incHours' && timerTime + 3600000 < max) {
        this.setState({timerTime: timerTime + 3600000})
      } else if (input === 'decHours' && timerTime - 3600000 >= 0) {
        this.setState({ timerTime: timerTime - 3600000 })
      } else if (input === 'incMinutes' && timerTime + 60000 < max) {
        this.setState({timerTime: timerTime + 60000})
      } else if (input === 'decMinutes' && timerTime - 60000 >= 0) {
        this.setState({timerTime: timerTime - 60000})
      } else if (input === 'incSeconds' && timerTime + 1000 < max) {
        this.setState({timerTime: timerTime + 1000})
      } else if (input === 'decSeconds' && timerTime - 1000 >= 0) {
        this.setState({timerTime: timerTime - 1000})
      }
    }
  }


  render() {
    const { timerTime, timerStart, timerOn } = this.State;
    let seconds = ('0' + (Math.floor((timerTime / 1000) % 60) % 60)).slice(-2)
    let minutes = ('0' + (Math.floor((timerTime / 60000) % 60))).slice(-2)
    let hours = ('0' + (Math.floor((timerTime / 3600000) % 60))).slice(-2)

    return (
      <div className='countdown'>
        <div className='countdown-header'>
          <div className='countdown-label'>Hours : Minutes : Seconds</div>
          <div className='countdown-display'>
            <button onClick={() => this.adjustTimer('incHours')}>&#8679;</button>
            <button onClick={() => this.adjustTimer('incMinutes')}>&#8679;</button>
            <button onClick={() => this.adjustTimer('incSeconds')}>&#8679;</button>
            <div className='countdown-time'>{hours} : {minutes} : {seconds}</div>
            <button onClick={() => this.adjustTimer('decHours')}>&#8681;</button>
            <button onClick={() => this.adjustTimer('decMinutes')}>&#8681;</button>
            <button onClick={() => this.adjustTimer('decSeconds')}>&#8681;</button>
          </div>
          {timerOn === false && (timerStart === 0 || timerTime === timerStart) && (<button onClick={this.startTimer}>Start</button>)}
          {timerOn === true && (timerStart >= 1000 && (<button onClick={this.stopTimer}>Stop</button>))}
          {timerOn === false && (timerStart !== 0 && timerStart !== timerTime && timerTime !== 0) && (<button onClick={this.startTimer}>Resume</button>)}
          {(timerOn === false || timerTime < 1000) && (timerStart !== timerTime && timerStart > 0) && (<button onClick={this.resetTimer}>Reset</button>)}
        </div>
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

Thanks for your help!

Comment: hey, have you looked at the react docs for defining classes and how state is initialised? As I think that would be a good place to start.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a typo. Javascript is case-sensitive so it should be `this.state` not `this.State`.

Try this:

```
const { timerTime, timerStart, timerOn } = this.state;
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I knew it had to be something really small.

Comment: @Andy F if it fixed your issue would you mind marking this as the answer? thanks